# My jQuery isn't working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

My website is https://www.jordanstechworld.com/

I am trying to make it to where when the top of my "about-title" is at about half way of the viewport, my text turns red. The problem is that my text is red all the time. I have spent hours trying to find solutions of SOF and have tried multiple different things. I am using this for my jQuery

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300){
        $('#about-title').css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Home - Jordan's Tech World</title>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css"/>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/affe0d5d11.js"></script>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
            <meta name="theme-color" content="#1F4F8E"/>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="main-hero">
              <i id="side-toggle" class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              <div class="main-nav">
                <ul>
                  <img id="nav-logo" src="./images/logo-small.png" alt="">
                  <li id="about-btn"><a href="about">About</a></li>
                  <li id="portfolio-btn"><a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                  <li id="development-btn"><a href="development">Development</a></li>
                  <li id="login-btn"><a href="login"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="side-nav">
                <i id="side-toggle-small" class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <ul>
                  <li id="side-about-btn"><a href="about">About</a></li>
                  <li id="side-portfolio-btn"><a href="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                  <li id="side-development-btn"><a href="development">Development</a></li>
                  <li id="side-login-btn"><a href="login"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <a href="https://www.jordanstechworld.com/"><img id="logo" src="./images/logo.png" alt="JTW Logo"></a>
            </div>
            <i id="scroll-arrow" class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <div id="content">
                <h1 id="about-title">About Me</h1>
                <div id="container">
                    <div id="left-box">
                      <p>I am a 17 year old Journeyman Web Developer, Java Developer, and gaming enthusiast. I started getting into HTML, CSS, and dabbling into JQuery slightly. I can make some pretty impressive looking things happen, given time.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="right-box">
                        <p>I am a 17 year old Journeyman Web Developer, Java Developer, and gaming enthusiast. I started getting into HTML, CSS, and dabbling into JQuery slightly. I can make some pretty impressive looking things happen, given time.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>

$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300){
        $('#about-title').css('color', 'red');
    }
});


$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      var elementOffset = $('#about-title').offset().top;
      var currentElementOffset = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

      console.log(currentElementOffset);
   });
});

              $(document).scroll(function(){
                if($('#left-box').scrollTop() <= 406){
                  $('#left-box').addClass('slide');
                  console.log("Reached");
                }
                else {
                  $('#left-box').removeClass('slide');
                }
              });

              $("#side-toggle").click(function() {
                $('.side-nav').toggleClass('open');
              });

              $("#side-toggle-small").click(function() {
                $('.side-nav').toggleClass('open');
              });

              $("#scroll-arrow").click(function() {
                $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top - 150
              }, 1500);
              });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
</doctype>
```

Comment: Please create a working fiddle so that we can replicate separately.

Comment: @scooterlord https://jsfiddle.net/kjue9e1h/2/ maybe this will work?

Comment: @scooterlord link updated.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032900/css-change-background-color-at-certain-point/44033253#44033253

Comment: @JulianEspinosa ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here goes. Your example actually works, it's the scrollTop value that is wrong. Explanation coming shortly.

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= ($('#about-title').offset().top-$(window).height()/2)){
        $('#about-title').css('color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kjue9e1h/6/

Edit: If you check on your inspector the code works as it should. The thing is that the document scrolls a lot more than 300px. My code below is just an approximation, but what you should do is try to figure out how to create your layout so that you can measure the document scroll before your element.

Edit2: Here is an improvement to restore color if the scroll conditions aren't met.

https://jsfiddle.net/kjue9e1h/7/

You should try creating the fiddle properly next time, with each type of code in its corresponding window. Also, try simplifying your code by removing unnecessary classes and/or ids.

Edit3: Based on your comment, here is how to restore the color:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= ($('#about-title').offset().top-$(window).height()/2)){
      $('#about-title').attr('style', 'color:red');
    } else {
        $('#about-title').attr('style','');
    }
});
```

If the condition is met, color is changed to red, if not it is removed. In my code instead of applying colors directly inline, I would create a class and add/remove that instead of applying colors directly.

In order to make sure it is absolutely centered, you should also remove half the height of your `#about-title` element, but I don't think it would be necessary. However here it is:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= ($('#about-title').offset().top-$(window).height()/2)-$('#about-title').height()){
      $('#about-title').attr('style', 'color:red');
    } else {
        $('#about-title').attr('style','');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kjue9e1h/8/

Comment: Using that, on my actual page it doesn't work. The text is red all the time. Why? On fiddle it works though.

Comment: Try removing pieces of code part by part until you sort out what's wrong. At first glance, just using the inspector shows a lot of 'reds'.. Also it's a good tactic to put Javascript files/scripts at the bottom of the page, right before the closing </body> tag.

Comment: Well, without the proper tools you can't expect to do proper work I'm afraid. Try removing the rest of the scroll bindings to make sure that they aren't messing with each other. Also, since the fiddle works as it should, you should accept this as the right answer. I will try to help you with your problem nevertheless.

Comment: I accepted it as the answer...I just wish this would work. I really don't want to have to recode everything. Let me get rid of some of them and retry. Give me a minute

Comment: It's still not working.... does it have something to do with the structure of my HTML?

Comment: Whenever something that was supposed to work doesn't, I try stripping my file part-by-part until it works. Let me know what happens

Comment: For some reason my navbar stopped appearing (jQuery activated on page load)... I am so confused I didn't even touch anything.

Comment: As a sidenote, try using this plugin, it does most of what you are trying to achieve: https://scrollrevealjs.org/

Comment: I like having stuff I do myself

Comment: Most of us do, but you'll come around :)

Comment: I might just have no other choice but to recode the entire thing.

Edit: Can I use jQuery inside of a .js (javascript) file and link it like with my css?

Comment: Alright, this is my last comment for now. I will work on this once I get back home. I had an older version of my index and css opened in my tabs on this computer and re-uploaded them and it overwrote everything I had. *sigh*. Good thing I have it all still open in Atom at home. Thanks for the help I'll comment later. My discord is Squallz#5777 if you can help me figure this stuff out it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should just add an `else` condition to the `scroll` event handler. Something like:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= 300){
        $('#about-title').css('color', 'red');
    } else {
        $('#about-title').css('color', 'white');
    }
});
```

Of course, you can change the color to the value you like.

Also, if you intend to change the color based on the offset from top, you could use the `currentElementOffset` variable that you are already calculating. So your code might be something like this:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var elementOffset = $('#about-title').offset().top;
    var currentElementOffset = (elementOffset - scrollTop);

    console.log(currentElementOffset);

    if(currentElementOffset >= 300){
        $('#about-title').css('color', 'red');
    } else {
        $('#about-title').css('color', 'white');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably checking the wrong element for scroll.  I'd recommend either using `$(window).on('scroll', ...)` or `$(document.body).on('scroll', ...)`

The reason being that the `document` object itself isn't a scrollable object, as it refers to the `html` element on the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= ($('#content')/2)){
        $('#about-title').css('color', 'red');
    } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= ($('#content')/2)) {
        $('#about-title').css('color', 'white');
     }
});
```