# CSS Header effect (change background and color) when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do a nice effect when the header leaves the current block. I want the background color and the color of the text to change when scrolling down.

html:

```
<header class="green">Logo</header>
<header class="red">Logo</header>

<section id='content1'>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Goes here!</p>
</section>
<section id='content2'>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Goes here!</p>
</section>
```

css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 20pt;
  padding: 15px 10px
}

.green {
  background: green;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2

}
.red {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 100px 10px
}

#content1 {
  background: #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 1
}

#content2 {
  background: #9FDAD0;
  z-index: 2
}
```

An example serves best, something like this https://www.dropbox.com/

Thanks!

Comment: iám pretty sure they also used javascript to pull it off, so i've editted the tag javascript into the question.

Comment: Check this it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44032900/css-change-background-color-at-certain-point/44033253#44033253

Comment: So onscroll check position and apply a class

Comment: I dont want to change the color of the hole header. Want the header to be smooth and to fit the background 100%. I think this is possible with eg z-index and two headers like the code above, but I am missing something :P

Comment: It seams W3C is working on it to make this part of css https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scroll-snap/   ... it's seams to be supported by Firefox and some other browser looking into this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type  ... here is a "polyfill" https://hospodarets.com/css-scroll-snap

Comment: You can steal my styles & js off [this site](http://professionalsweb.com/proweb) if ya like. I left it unminified for that purpose.

Comment: There is really no need to dupe your header, just one and you swap the class, It is listening for the scroll and than applying the class when it is in the right zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i redid it with some Javascript.
This effect is awesome, feel free to improve it if you like!
Is this possible to accomplish without Javascript?

```js
const secondBlock = document.getElementById('content2')
const header = document.getElementsByTagName('header')
const headerHeight = 61

function setHeader () {
  const scrollPoint = window.pageYOffset + headerHeight

  let blockPoint = 61 - (scrollPoint - secondBlock.offsetTop)
  if (blockPoint <= 0) { blockPoint = 0 }

  if (scrollPoint > secondBlock.offsetTop) {
    header[0].style = `max-height: ${blockPoint}px;`
  } else {
    header[0].style = `max-height: ${headerHeight}px;`
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(setHeader)
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(setHeader)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20pt;
  height: 61px;
  line-height: 61px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

header#first {
  background: #8292C3;
  color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

header#second {
  background: #82C3B9;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 9;
}

section {
  height: 500px;
  padding: 100px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#content1 {
  background: #96A6D5;
}

#content2 {
  background: #99D6CC;
}
```

```html
<header id='first'>Logo - <small>scroll down to see the magic!</small></header>
<header id='second'>Logo - <small>scroll down to see the magic! COOL!</small></header>

<section id='content1'>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Goes here!</p>
</section>
<section id='content2'>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Goes here!</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The smooth transition you're looking for can be done in CSS, but you'll need some JavaScript in order to initiate the animation.

```js
window.onscroll = function(){
  var top = window.scrollY;
  console.log('Top: ' + top);
                var header = document.getElementsByTagName('header');
                var offset = header.innerHeight; //changed offset to be dynamic, so it works on mobile screens.
  if(top > offset){
      header[0].classList.remove('top');
      header[0].classList.add('scrolled');
  } else {
                    header[0].classList.remove('scrolled');
                    header[0].classList.add('top');
                }
 };
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
 position: relative;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 75px;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 20pt;
  padding: 15px 10px
}
header.top {
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

header.scrolled {
 background: #555;
 color: #e0e0e0;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2

}
.red {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1
}

section {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 100px 10px
}

#content1 {
  background: #D9D9D9;
  z-index: 1
}

#content2 {
  background: #9FDAD0;
  z-index: 2
}
```

```html
 <header class="top">Logo</header>
 <section id='content1'>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Goes here!</p>
</section>
<section id='content2'>
  <h1>Content</h1>
  <p>Goes here!</p>
</section>
```

This basically says that when we scroll passed the height of the header (in this case 50px), remove the "top" class from it, and add the "scrolled" class from it. You can use the css selectors `header.top` and `header.scrolled` to do your transition animations. Be sure to use `transition: background-color (time) (timing function), color (time) (timing function);` to achieve the smoothness you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, this works but its not what I am after, look at https://www.dropbox.com/ header.

Comment: Dropbox's header doesn't change colors, sizes, or anything. For this, all you need is the `position:fixed; top:0` CSS call, and to make sure that your `body` is `position: relative;` so that the position of elements inside it work. **EDIT:** the only other thing I see is maybe the box shadow under the header, so it looks like it stands above the page? But otherwise I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it with the class. Like i use this website.

http://www.moumaachi.com/
it has class like this

```
 <div class="header-v2 navbar-fixed-top">
```

but when scroll down to 50 px then it will showa this

```
<div class="header-v2 navbar-fixed-top top-nav-collapse">
```

and normal it has

```
<div class="thiswillhide">
```

but when scroll down more then it wil like this

```
<div class="thiswillhide hidesearch">
```

you can use this code

```
<script>
    //jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(".header-v2").offset().top > 50) {
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
        } else {
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
        }
        if ($(".header-v2").offset().top > 600) {
            $(".thiswillhide").addClass("hidesearch");
        } else {
            $(".thiswillhide").removeClass("hidesearch");
        }
    });
</script>
```

thanks